# Mercury in a U-tube

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, fluid-statics

I was doing this simple problem from White's Fluid Mechanics' Chapter 2, where I have this U-tube [image]

which has a 1 cm internal diameter and contains mercury as shown.
If 20 cm$^3$ of water is poured into the right-hand
leg, what will the free-surface height in each leg
be, once equilibrium is reached?
I thought that, by adding $\approx 25,46$ cm of height of water, the mercury's height on the right side would decrease by a constant $h$, so I would get $(10-h) $ cm of mercury and $(10+h)$ cm on the left side. Using the hydrostatic equation,

$p_{atm}+(10+h)\gamma_{Hg}-(10-h)\gamma_{Hg}-0.2546\gamma_{water}=p_{atm}$

and solve it for $h$, I get $0.9376$ cm which is incorrect, according to White's Solutions. Where am I wrong?

Comment: did you mean 10+h on the left? And what is the meaning of the symbol $\gamma$?

Comment: Yes, 10+h, my mistake! $\gamma=\rho g$ stands for the specific weight

Comment: also, 0.2546 should be 25.46, no?

Comment: Also, note that you're asked for the free surface height, so the correct answer should be 10+h on the left and 10-h+25.46 on the right

Comment: The heights in the formula are all in meters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concentrate for a moment on the $25.45$ cm of water added to the RHS.

Since the specific gravity of mercury is $13.6$, this height of water exerts the same pressure as $25.46/13.6$ or $1.87$ cm of mercury.

So half of this additional "pseudo-mercury" height, or $0.94$ cm of mercury has to migrate to the LHS;  the LHS mercury level **goes up** to $10.94$ cm.

Returning to the RHS, the mercury-water boundary will **drop** by this same $0.94$ cm.  Adding the $25.4$ cm of actual water height, gives a height for the new surface of $10-0.94+25.45$ or $34.51$ cm.

Comment: Oh! I was actually right xD I checked the solutions again and my professor wrote the final result wrong by a factor of 10^-3. Anyway, thank you very much for your time!